# Is a listing available of singlethreaded and multithreded libaries and applications / services?

Tags: multithreading, command-line

Using Linux. Does there exist database or listing of what libraries, binaries, applicationa, services are singlethreaded vs the ones which are multithreaded ? Or is there a simple way to extract this information from the files presented ?

Answer (score 2):

If they are open source (as are nearly all the programs on Linux), you can check in the source to see if any threading libraries and/or headers are involved. Probably looking through the source files and reading the includes could be a clue...